# ピリオドで区切られた数値の差の計算方法

Tags: php

お世話になります。

プログラミングとはあまり関係ないかもしれないのですが、アイデアをいただければと思い、質問させていただきました。
　タイトルの通りなんですが、PHPで、よくバージョン情報の表記等で見かける

1.2.3.4

や

1.2.3.5

のように、ピリオドで区切られた数値の差を求めるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

例えば、

```
<?php
echo 1.2.3.5-1.2.3.4;
?>
```

のようにしましたが、予想通りエラーになってしまいます。
　何かよい方法があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `1.2.3.5-1.2.3.4` の期待する結果としては `0.0.0.1` ということでよろしいですか？

Comment: そうですね。ただ、後で条件判定をすることを考えると、1のほうがいいかもしれないです。

Comment: リビジョンナンバーが連続しているのかどうか、最終ナンバーはどうなっているのかが分からないと計算できない事に気が付きました。例えば `1.2.4.1` と `1.2.3.2` の差分を考えますと、`1.2.3.9` の次が `1.2.4.0` なのか、それとも `1.2.3.49` や `1.2.3.213` の次が `1.2.4.0` になる等々です。なので、対象のプログラムの改変履歴を参照しないと具体的な差分は分からないのではないかと思います。

Comment: お世話になります。回答でも教えていただきましたが、PHPには「version_compare」という関数があるようで、今回はこれで何とかなりそうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

数値で差分を取って意味があるのでしょうか？

版数の上下同比較であれば、[version_compare](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.version-compare.php) という関数があります。

[PHP でバージョン番号の比較方法と確認方法（各種）](https://qiita.com/KEINOS/items/cf25f6ffe215ff44c901)

どうしても数値として扱いたいなら、[explode](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.explode.php) 関数でピリオドをデリミタにして配列を取得し、数値に変換して、インデックス毎の個々の差分を計算するという方法が考えられます。

Comment: お世話になります。教えていただき、ありがとうございます。PHPには、「version_compare」という便利な関数があったんですね。今回はこれで何とかなりそうです。ありがとうございました。